# make makes not written rules

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

Here is my makefile code :

```
CC      = gcc
IFLAGS  = -Iinclude
CFLAGS  = -std=c99 -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c # -march=native -ggdb3
LFLAGS  = -shared -lX11 # -march=native -ggdb3
DFLAGS  = -L./lib -lOSPOOC

TARGET  = lib/libOSPOOC.so
SOURCES = $(shell echo src/*.c)
HEADERS = $(shell echo include/*.h)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(SOURCES))

# CURLIBPATH = $(PWD)/lib
# LDLIBPATH = $(shell echo $(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) | grep $(CURLIBPATH))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

*.o: *.c
    echo allo
    $(CC) $(IFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

demo: $(TARGET) demo/windows.c
    $(CC) $(IFLAGS) -o bin/windows demo/windows.c $(DFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -r */*.o */*.so bin/*
```

The rule *.o is not called, and, I don't know how, but it compiles correctly...

Result :

```
make demo
gcc -std=c99 -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c    -c -o src/OSPobj.o src/OSPobj.c
gcc -std=c99 -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c    -c -o src/OSPutl.o src/OSPutl.c
gcc -std=c99 -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c    -c -o src/OSPwin.o src/OSPwin.c
gcc -shared -lX11  -o lib/libOSPOOC.so src/OSPobj.o src/OSPutl.o src/OSPwin.o
gcc -Iinclude -o bin/windows demo/windows.c -L./lib -lOSPOOC
```

The problem is that -c is used twice, and echo allo isn't event called...

What do I don't understand, why do I have this strange behaviour?

Comment: [make implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html)

Comment: Your targets are prefixed by `src` and hence do not match your explicit `*.c` rule. So the implicit rule is used instead.

Comment: Sorry to waist your time, that was a stupid question.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that's not *.o: *.c but %.o: %.c

*.o is for bash, %.o is for make